# Multiple Line in single stacked text box using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript

I am having difficulties with creating a stacked label based on different soil boring depth.

Below is my attribute table:

[image]

I want to display something like this stacked in 1 text box:

[image]

Every time I use my script I get multiple text boxes and then have to copy and paste them in to 1 text box.

My VBScript is:

```
[GIS_SB_Ben] &vbCrLf & [GIS_SB_B_1] +" - "+ [GIS_SB_B_2] &vbCrLf & "Benzene = "+ [GIS_SB_B_3]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your script here so we may see it.

Also under the labels tab in the layer properties you can define a statement for the labels is this what you are using?

Comment: You talk about stacked labels and also about stacked text boxes.  Are you trying to achieve this by using labelling or by using text graphics?  If I were trying to stack labels then I would use the Python Parser.  What ArcGIS version are you using?  The Python Parser for labelling has not always been available.  What does the VBScript that you have presented display like?  i.e. how close are you already to achieving what you want.

Comment: Are you locations, I assume identified by your field GIS_SB_Ben, stacked points or are they distributed as it appears you are trying to group your labelling by the GIS_SB_Ben field? But each row could be completely different geometries?